# Easy way to apply transformation from `pandas.get_dummies` to new data?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame `data` with strings that I want converted to indicators. I use `pandas.get_dummies(data)` to convert this to a dataset that I can now use for building a model.

Now I have a single new observation that I want to run through my model. Obviously I can't use `pandas.get_dummies(new_data)` because it doesn't contain all of the classes and won't make the same indicator matrices. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

you can create the dummies from the single new observation, and then reindex this frames columns using the columns from the original indicator matrix:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat':['a','b','c','d'],'val':[1,2,5,10]})
df1 = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame({'cat':['a'],'val':[1]}))
dummies_frame = pd.get_dummies(df)
df1.reindex(columns = dummies_frame.columns, fill_value=0)
```

returns:

```
        val     cat_a   cat_b   cat_c   cat_d
  0     1       1       0       0       0
```

Comment: You probably want fill_value=0.

Comment: God, I love stack overflow.

Comment: this would mean having the entire training dataframe in memory at inference time!?

Comment: @marbel No, you would only need the column index.

Comment: This works if the test data contains no unseen values for the category. But what if it does? The correct solution would to lump it into "others" category. How to efficiently implement this?

Comment: @Nick It handles unseen classes by using all zeros. You can imagine this as an "other" class. There really nothing else one can do if you don't know the new classes beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching out JAB's answer in order to use it for example in sklearn pipelines, this code may help you:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class GetDummies(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, dummy_columns):
        self.columns = None
        self.dummy_columns = dummy_columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.columns = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=self.dummy_columns).columns
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X_new = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=self.dummy_columns)
        return X_new.reindex(columns=self.columns, fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can take the advantage of type `category`.

```py
import pandas as pd


train = pd.DataFrame({'feature':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
test = pd.DataFrame({'feature':['a']})

train['feature'] = train['feature'].astype('category')
dummies_type = train['feature'].dtype
test['feature'] = test['feature'].astype(dummies_type)
```

training data:

```
pd.get_dummies(train)

feature_a   feature_b   feature_c   feature_d
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   1   0
0   0   0   1
```

testing data:

```
pd.get_dummies(test)

feature_a   feature_b   feature_c   feature_d
1   0   0   0
```

new value of the feature:

```
test_oov = pd.DataFrame({'feature':['z']})
test_oov['feature'] = test_oov['feature'].astype(dummies_type)
pd.get_dummies(test_oov)

feature_a   feature_b   feature_c   feature_d
0   0   0   0
```