# Pandas Get_dummies for nested tables

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to utilize pandas get_dummy() functionality to encode a (quite extensive) set of categorical variables. However the data is currently in nested table format. Meaning that each row represents another variable instance for example

```
Instance, Cat_Col
1, John
1, Smith
2, Jane
3, Joe
```

Now I can generate the full list of unique variables which I can use to get_dummies which represent all possible values. However transforming the nested table into a single instance row in this new format is giving me some trouble.

Any help is much appreciated 
Thanks

Edit: 
each instance should have a dummy coding result for all values of Cat_col

The idea would be the result be a single feature vector like so

```
Instance,Col_John,Col_Smith,Col_Jane,Col_Joe
1,1,1,0,0
2,0,0,1,0
3,0,0,0,1
```

I believe that is the correct coding, assuming we are doing 1-hot encoding

Comment: Do you need a dummy for each unique 'Instance' or 'Cat_Col' or some combination of both? What would the dummy result for your example look like?

Comment: @StefanJansen the question above has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider using `pivot_table` to achieve your goal here.

```
import pandas as pd

df

Out[10]: 
   Instance Cat_Col
0         1    John
1         1   Smith
2         2    Jane
3         3     Joe

df['count'] = 1
df.pivot('Instance', 'Cat_Col', 'count').fillna(0)

Out[11]: 
Cat_Col    Jane   Joe   John   Smith
Instance                            
1             0     0      1       1
2             1     0      0       0
3             0     1      0       0
```

If you prefer to use `get_dummies`,

```
result = pd.get_dummies(df.Cat_Col)
result['Instance'] = df.Instance
result = result.set_index('Instance')
result.groupby(level=0).apply(max)

Out[26]: 
           Jane   Joe   John   Smith
Instance                            
1             0     0      1       1
2             1     0      0       0
3             0     1      0       0
```

Comment: This looks good, my only concern is that this is just reformatting the table, and doesn't give the flexibility to encode new entries as as would pandas get_dummies (see link)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465633/easy-way-to-apply-transformation-from-pandas-get-dummies-to-new-data

Comment: @user1874538 I've updated the code to use `get_dummies`. Have a look. :-)

Comment: Perfect this exactly what I was looking for, great use of the max since they are all 1 anyway. (as a side node the pivot example above does not work if Cat_col is not unique)

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.get_dummies(df1.set_index("Instance")).reset_index().groupby("Instance",as_index=False).sum()


┌──────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Instance │ Cat_Col_Jane │ Cat_Col_Joe │ Cat_Col_John │ Cat_Col_Smith │
│ varchar  │    uint8     │    uint8    │    uint8     │     uint8     │
├──────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┤
│ 1        │            0 │           0 │            1 │             1 │
│ 2        │            1 │           0 │            0 │             0 │
│ 3        │            0 │           1 │            0 │             0 │
└──────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘
```