# Pandas Groupby - Sparse Matrix Error

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This question is related to the question I asked previously about using pandas get_dummies() function (link below).

[Pandas Get_dummies for nested tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255865/pandas-get-dummies-for-nested-tables)

However in the course of utilizing the solution provide in the answer I noticed odd behavior when looking at the groupby function. The issue is that repeated (non-unique) index values for a dataframe appear to cause an error when the matrix is represented in sparse format, while working as expected for dense matrix.

I have extremely high dimensional data thus sparse matrix will be required for memory reasons. An example of the error is below. If anyone has a work around it would be greatly appreciated

Working:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Instance':[1,1,2,3],'Cat_col':        
['John','Smith','Jane','Doe']})
result= pd.get_dummies(df.Cat_col, prefix='Name')
result['Instance'] = df.Instance
result = result.set_index('Instance')
result = result.groupby(level=0).apply(max)
```

Failing

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Instance':[1,1,2,3],'Cat_col':   
['John','Smith','Jane','Doe']})
result= pd.get_dummies(df.Cat_col, prefix='Name',sparse=True)
result['Instance'] = df.Instance
result = result.set_index('Instance')
result = result.groupby(level=0).apply(max)
```

Note you will need version 16.1 or greater of pandas.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The failed example works if changing the last line to `result = result.groupby(level=0).apply(sum)`

Answer (score 0):

You can perform your groupby in a different way as a workaround.  Don't set Instance as the index and use the column for your groupby and drop the Instance column (last column in this case since it was just added).  Groupby will will make an Instance index.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Instance':[1,1,2,3],'Cat_col':   
['John','Smith','Jane','Doe']})
result= pd.get_dummies(df.Cat_col, prefix='Name',sparse=True)
result['Instance'] = df.Instance
#WORKAROUND:
result=result.groupby('Instance').apply(max)[result.columns[:-1]]

result
Out[58]: 
          Name_Doe  Name_Jane  Name_John  Name_Smith
Instance                                            
1                0          0          1           1
2                0          1          0           0
3                1          0          0           0
```

Note: The sparse dataframe stores your Instance int's as floats within a BlockIndex in the dataframe column.  In order to have the index the exact same as the first example you'd need to change to int from float.

```
result.index=result.index.map(int)
result.index.name='Instance'
```