# Pandas categorical variable transformation

Tags: python, pandas

Data.csv: `param1,param2,param3,result
           1,2,cat1,12
           2,3,cat2,13
           1,6,cat1,6
           1,1,cat2,12`

Suppose i read the data from the file and convert categorical variables into dummy variables like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

type_dummies = pd.get_dummies(data.house_type)
data = pd.concat([data, type_dummies], axis=1)
```

I received dataframe:

```
1,2,1,0,..
1,6,0,1,..
```

I made simple linear regression for that dataset and received coeffs. How can i convert a new record (new_data = np.array([12,19,cat1])) for new_data = np.array([12,19,1,0)) using pandas for using it in my linear model? (such that new data categorical variables will be converted into dummy variables)

Comment: See @JAB's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28466662/2285236

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'll want to setup a pipeline to record the correct `category:code` mapping.

```
class CategoricalTransformer(TransformerMixin):

    def fit(self, X, y=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.columns_ = X.columns
        self.cat_columns_ = X.select_dtypes(include=['category']).columns
        self.non_cat_columns_ = X.columns.drop(self.cat_columns_)

        self.cat_map_ = {col: X[col].cat.categories
                         for col in self.cat_columns_}
        self.ordered_ = {col: X[col].cat.ordered
                         for col in self.cat_columns_}

        self.dummy_columns_ = {col: ["_".join([col, v])
                                     for v in self.cat_map_[col]]
                               for col in self.cat_columns_}
        self.transformed_columns_ = pd.Index(
            self.non_cat_columns_.tolist() +
            list(chain.from_iterable(self.dummy_columns_[k]
                                     for k in self.cat_columns_))
        )

    def transform(self, X, y=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return (pd.get_dummies(X)
                  .reindex(columns=self.transformed_columns_)
                  .fillna(0))
```

More [here](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/categorical-pipelines.html).

with the pipeline `sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline(CategoricalTransformer(), LinearRegression())`, your `predict` method should correctly translate from the categorical `house_type` to variables.

Comment: Link tomaugspurger.github.io/categorical-pipelines.html is dead. Gives 404