# Using reindex with fill_value for categorical and continuous features in same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm using `pandas.get_dummies` to encode categorical features at the time of fitting and classification and I just noticed that the `Imputer()` is putting averages in the "off" categorical switches added in `dataframe.reindex()` at the time of classification of a new sample.

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465633/easy-way-to-apply-transformation-from-pandas-get-dummies-to-new-data) suggesting to use `fill_value=0` on the `reindex` call which seems like a nice solution but I have one nagging question before I push this code into production.

Does anyone know if pandas DataFrame.reindex function will set all NaN to the value in fill_value or only the new columns it adds?  I'd like to make sure any non categorical data with NaN is handled by the `Imputer()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe it will fill the NaN values in all the columns.

From [http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html][1]

```
import pandas as pd
index = ['Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'IE10', 'Konqueror']
new_index= ['Safari', 'Iceweasel', 'Comodo Dragon', 'IE10','Chrome']
df = pd.DataFrame({
      'http_status': [200,200,404,404,301],
      'response_time': [0.04, 0.02, 0.07, 0.08, 1.0]},
       index=index)

df
```

Returns:

```
                http_status  response_time
Firefox            200           0.04
Chrome             200           0.02
Safari             404           0.07
IE10               404           0.08
Konqueror          301           1.00
```

While `df.reindex(new_index, fill_value='missing')` Returns:

```
                  http_status   response_time
Safari                404          0.07
Iceweasel         missing       missing
Comodo Dragon     missing       missing
IE10                  404          0.08
Chrome                200          0.02
```

Neither of these columns are new, but the nan values are still filled in. I would definitely test my explanation though before putting into production. I'm not sure if I have the proper context.

Edit:

I should add that it seems as though if the values were 'NaN' before, the .reindex will not fill those values:

```
import pandas as pd
index = ['Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'IE10', 'Konqueror']
new_index= ['Safari', 'Iceweasel', 'Comodo Dragon', 'IE10','Chrome']
df = pd.DataFrame({
      'http_status': [200,'NaN',404,404,301],
      'response_time': [0.04, 0.02, 0.07, 0.08, 1.0]},
       index=index)

df
```

Returns:

```
               http_status  response_time
Safari                404           0.07
Iceweasel             NaN            NaN
Comodo Dragon         NaN            NaN
IE10                  404           0.08
Chrome                NaN           0.02
```

While  df.reindex(new_index, fill_value='missing') returns:

```
              http_status response_time
Safari                404          0.07
Iceweasel         missing       missing
Comodo Dragon     missing       missing
IE10                  404          0.08
Chrome                NaN          0.02
```

The HTTP Status-Chrome value was not affected by switching the index.

Comment: Thanks for the response @cptnhaddock.  This is very helpful!